# Books within the Quran

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic-translation, surat-al-baqarah

Is the Holy Quran one book? Or Is the Holy Quran a collection of multiple distinct books (each with a name and signs)?  In reference to 98:2-3 and multiple different verses which different books are named. Eg- al kitab, om al kitab, al quran, al zabur, etc etc. Beginning with 2:2 and the age old question- the Arabic word thalika al kitab being interpreted as “this book” and not “that book”.

Comment: This question is a mix of different topics. Maybe you should consider focusing it a bit more.